# Fix position the span.bubble in css to the right

Tags: css, angularjs, slider

I'm creating an RGB slider using angularJS and rzslider but I have a little problem in here and need some help. I want the value box or the `span.bubble` in css to be fixed on the right side. Please see screenshot below:

[image: RGB Slider]

Here's what I have now.

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/645c59NhsLLhXpmEDxl8?p=preview)

I prefer css solution but if it's not possible, any solutions will do. :)

Comment: NVM I already figured it out.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it, in case anyone else has a similar issue!

Comment: Ok sure @speak I will post the solution. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured It out after posting the question, I read the docs again. Here's the updated code.

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/645c59NhsLLhXpmEDxl8?p=preview)

Instead of using the `span.bubble` css as the result output, I hid it and created

```
<span class="color-slider-result">{{color}}</span>
```

and changed the name of `span.bubble` to `span.color-slider-result`.